# XSLT split sorted data into different tables

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

I'm trying to format my xml data into two HTML tables. I successfully can sort some dummy data xls:sort, but I can't split up the sorted data into different tables.

My xml:

```
<a>
    <b id="N">text1</b>
    <b id="N">text2</b>
    <b id="N+1">text3</b>
    <b id="N">text4</b>
    <b id="N+2">text5</b>
    <b id="N+3">text6</b>
    <b id="N">text7</b>
    <b id="N+2">text8</b>
</a>
```

N is in this case a number, but I don't know which number. It could be 2 and 55, 3 and 4, 44 and 52 and 78 and 98.

Each number I wish to send to their own table, so the result would be:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>text1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text7</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><td>text3</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><td>text5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text8</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr><td>text6</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I devide the sorted data into different tables depending on their attribute?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  The latter is easier.

Comment: We use version 1.0 im afraid.

Comment: Show the xslt that you have tried please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard approach to this kind of problem in XSLT 1.0 is called *Muenchian grouping*.  You define a key that groups your target elements in the way you want

```
<xsl:key name="bsById" match="b" use="@id" />
```

then use a trick with `generate-id` to extract just the *first* node in each group as a proxy for the group as a whole

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="b[generate-id()
                             = generate-id(key('bsById', @id)[1])]"
                     mode="group">
  <xsl:sort select="@id" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

So now the following template would fire once per group, and you can use the `key` function within it to get *all* the nodes in the group

```
<xsl:template match="b" mode="group">
  <table>
    <!-- extract all the nodes that are grouped with this one -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bsById', @id)">
      <!-- you could <xsl:sort> here if you want to sort within groups -->
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <tr><td>...</td></tr>
</xsl:template>
```

All the above is fine if that example is your entire XML document, but if there's more than one `a` element within the document each with its own set of `b` elements that need grouping independently, then the key needs to be more complex.  The usual trick here is to use the `generate-id` of the parent `a` node as part of the grouping key value for its `b` children:

```
<xsl:key name="bsByParentAndId" match="a/b" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @id)" />
```

and for the Muenchian grouping expression

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="b[generate-id()
                               = generate-id(key('bsByParentAndId', concat(
                                   generate-id(current()), '|', @id))[1])]"
                       mode="group"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

For the record, if you could use XSLT 2.0 then it becomes significantly easier.  No need to define a complex key, you simply use [`for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="b" group-by="@id">
    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" />
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
    </table>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
  <tr><td>...</td></tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It does the job perfect, thanks for the extra part where I have more than one <a> since I do. Also thanks for making it all, didn't expect that. Now I'll just gotta understand it all.